# Can I switch from Debian to Arch?

Tags: arch-linux

I'm a Debian user for the last four years.

I'm using KDE Plasma but I want to make Manjaro KDE version as my production system so since it is Arch based and rolling system I thought would be difficult to use.

I'm a Java developer so I just want Oracle JDK and NetBeans.
I had tried Arch Linux but I wasn't able to install any software.

So can I find Oracle JDK, Netbeans, and other popular software in octopi?
What are the basic differences between the useful commands of Ubuntu and Arch Linux?
So can I easily use it as an alternative?

Comment: Your question seems to be ambiguous,  could you edit and add details about what pieces of software you were not able to install / use. The current description is not clear.

Comment: There are trade-offs between point release and rolling release. Point releases are more stable but often leave you with years old software. Rolling releases are always up-to-date, but your software might not work after update due to lack of testing.

Comment: So may I face fatal problem in rolling release?

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak No! You will not face fatal issues in a rolling release. It's just like your Android apps. Most developers test their apps rigorously (especially big ones) before releasing it, but some don't. Just like in Android, it is rare to come across updates that make your application useless. But to counter this, you have the feature to roll-back updates if you are that unlucky person. From my experience from the past 1 year, I got a problem only in one software: xdotool. Most people wouldn't have even heard of this app.

Comment: You can. I would not, but you can.

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia Thanks a lot even I didn't hear about xdotool. I'll switch soon.

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia Yes I've checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been a long time Debian (Ubuntu, elementary, Bodhi, Linux Mint) user and transitioned to Arch (Manjaro XFCE) about a year ago.

**Software Availability**

Most of the software that I had used in Debian are available in Manjaro's repositories (can be installed using pacman). The remaining are almost always available in AUR (Arch User Repository).

If you prefer GUI, then Pamac is the default tool in Manjaro XFCE and it does a better job than Ubuntu's app center and package managers.

On doing a quick search in Pamac, I found that **Oracle JDK 6-10** is available in AUR. Note: You may have to enable AUR from Pamac's settings before using it. **Netbeans 10.0** is available in Manjaro's repository (doesn't need AUR).

**Commands**

From my experience, 85% of the commands are the same for Arch family. 5-10% of the commands are desktop specific. So if you are staying within KDE 90-95% of the commands will be the same.

The most notable difference is in commands of installing/uninstalling the software.
To install in Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

To install in Manjaro,

```
sudo pacman -S netbeans
```

To uninstall in Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get remove netbeans
```

To uninstall in Manjaro,

```
sudo pacman -R netbeans
```

[Debian VS Arch CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944687/terminal-commands-difference-between-ubuntu-and-manjaro)

**Easy to use**

I found Manjaro to be more easy to use than Ubuntu thanks to Pamac and AUR.

**Suggestion**

Make a live USB for Manjaro KDE, test the OS by booting from that USB and then decide if it suits you or not. While testing from your live USB, your installed OS and files will not be affected at all. If all goes well, you can install Manjaro KDE from that same live USB.